# How these conflicting scenarios will work in cassandra when one of the mode crashes?

Tags: cassandra

Say we have two nodes(simple replica no sharding) i.e. N1,N2  with replication factor as 2. I am using default Read and write consistency levels i.e. `R` and `W` are 1 which means it will read/write from/to single node

Scenario 1

1. Consider write request goes to node `N1`  to update record `R1`. Say name `scott` updated to `scott_update1`
2. Before it is replicated to `N2`, `N1` crashed
3. Another write request goes to node `N2`  to update the same record `R1`. Now `scott` updated to `scott_update2`
4. Now when `N1` comes back, will the name `scott_update1` be updated to `scott_update2` ?

Scenario 2

1. Consider write request goes to node `N1`  to update record `R1`. Say name `scott` updated to `scott_update1`
2. Before it is replicated to `N2`, `N1` crashed
3. Read request  goes to node `N2`  to read the same record `R1`. It returns `scott`
4. Now when `N1` comes back, will the name `scott_update1` be updated to `scott` or it will stay `scott_update1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both scenarios, everything depends on the how long the node `N1` was offline, and where the hints enabled or not...

In scenario 1, if downtime was less than 3 hours (default window to store hints), then the changes done when `N1` was offline will be replayed, and value will be updated to `scott_update2` because this value has greater timestamp. If downtime was larger than this window - then you need to run repair.

For scenario 2, there are 2 things - it could be eventually repaired when [read repair](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsRepairNodesReadRepair.html) happens, or you can explicitly run repair.

But talking about replication - write usually happens to all replicas at the same time, and consistency level specifies how many nodes need to answer to consider request as successful, so N2 could be updated as well in most cases.